# Can I down vote my own reputation?

Tags: support

I am dissatisfied with a recent up vote of my reputation. Is there any mechanism on EL&U that will allow me to down vote my own reputation?

Comment: Do you mean on a question or an answer?

Comment: I meant on a question. However, it just occurred to me that If I down voted my own question, I would know who down voted it, which violates the site's voter anonymity rule.

Answer (score 7):

You are, by design, prevented from voting on your own posts.  If you really think your question should not be upvoted, you can delete it (so long as it does not have upvoted answers; it if does, you would be unfairly reducing the repuation of others).

But you may also need to reconsider your view of reputation. It is not a negotiable currency (unfortunately) or a personal reward; it is an indication that others think this is a useful question, which should be marked out from the mass so that others may consider it.  What you think about this is in a sense irrelevant; so long as a question is not closed (which is a more technical point, and depends on the view of experienced users), every question is set adrift on the sea of public opinion, to gather votes and answers as it may.

Comment: I was up voted because I deleted the post. I will try to undelete the post and see if that does the trick. That's a good point about unfairly reducing the reputation of others who have up voted the question.

Comment: @Zan700: there's something wrong somewhere. If your reputation went up from a deletion, that can only be because the question had a negative score. If so, rest assured that is an intended outcome: there is even a badge (Peer Pressure) for deleting a low-score post.

Comment: Undeleting my question did indeed bring my reputation down three votes (the question had a negative three score). I did get one of those bowing to peer pressure badges, which I imagine will soon disappear. Do deleted questions remain forever, so that they can be undeleted?

Comment: Yes, deleted questions stick around forever, with the exception of things the powers that be delete with extreme prejudice (spam, mostly). But regular deleted questions can be and sometimes have been undeleted after years.

Comment: @DanBron - As I noted above, by undeleting my question I did successfully down vote myself, but they've yet to rip off my bowing to peer pressure badge. So I guess that once you've bowed, you've bowed forever.

Comment: @Zan700 Remember that SE is premised on gamification: every badge that exists was intentionally created to encourage the kinds of behavior the site values, and wants to see more of.  I have my own "Peer Pressure" badge, and I got it for deleting what turned out, in retrospect, to be a misleading answer. Everybody won: the OP, for not being confused by an incorrect answer, the downvoters, for getting what they wanted, me, for getting a badge, and all future visitors, for having a cleaner, better set of answers on that question.